# Windows authentication on IIS 10 removes the Administrators group

Tags: c#, iis, windows-authentication, iis-10, episerver-6

I'm running Windows 10 and have IIS 10 running a webpage with Windows Authentication. This worked fine on Windows 7 but I had to upgrade to 10 because of other dependencies.

The problem I have now is that when I login via the windows security prompt the Administrators group are not in the Identity's group list.

The user for the app pool that runs the site is a local administrator. And if I get the current user in code like this: `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` the Administrators group is available.

Is this a security thing? or are there some kind of setting I could change to get this to work?

We are running EPi server 6.1 if that could have anything to do with it.

Comment: In you app pool you can say which identity the app pool runs as. Default is network service. AFAIK this hasn't change between IIS versions

Comment: Yes, I have changed this to my local administrator account. Still no luck with the groups.

Comment: any update ? same issue..

Comment: any update ? same issue.. EventViewer said user is successfully logged on. must be asp.net or webapi issue?

Comment: No sorry :(
In the end the problem only manifested in the develop environment and we where able to login correctly by switching to Forms Authentication for dev and keeping Windows Authentication in production.